# All Word 2016 add-ins erroneously auto-open, doesn't respect "Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", sets taskpane visibility to "1"

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I've observed that O365 is consistent with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) on "Auto Open" behavior for Office.js taskpanes, but W2016 is not, so I'm wondering if this is a bug or if there's alternate instructions I should refer to.

I've tested this with my add-in, a newly created word add-in (template), and the Wikipedia add-in on the store.

Word documents saved in W2016 while an Office.js taskpane is open will auto-open, even if `Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument` is absent or set to false. This is because visibility is set to "1" in `word/webextensions/taskpanes.xml` (whereas its set to "0" in O365). For users who don't have the add-in installed, any document saved with the add-in open (even those with auto open absent or set to false) will show a blank add in.

1. Is this expected behavior, and if so, how can I programmatically (via Office.js, not by modifying the raw xml) ensure the add-in does not auto-open for docs created on W2016?
2. Is there a way to programmatically set the "visibility" setting for the add-in?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a bug. If you don't get an answer here in a few days, try raising an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).

Comment: thanks for opening this. @RickKirkham - we are experiencing a similar issue as well, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've filed a bug report here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2603